# How to joint the string in bash?

Tags: string, bash

```
sql="UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'domain','http://123.456.789.1/wp');"
echo $sql
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'domain','http://123.456.789.1/wp');
```

The sql string is what i want.
Assign the ip address to a variable.

```
$ip="123.456.789.1"
sql="UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'domain',"http://${ip}/wp");"
echo $sql
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'domain',http://123.456.789.7' /wp);
```

I can't get the sql string when ip address is a variable.
How to fix it?

Comment: `ip="123.456.789.1";  sql="UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'domain','"http://${ip}/wp"');"; echo "$sql"` should work fine

Comment: Don't construct SQL commands with string interpolation unless you are *positive* `ip` contains *just* an IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable names should not start with $. So call the variable `ip` instead of `$ip`.

Since your sql string is declared with double quotes, you don't need another double quotes inside `"http://${ip}/wp"`.

This should do the work:

```
ip="123.456.789.1"
sql="UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'domain','http://$ip/wp');"
echo "$sql"
```

Output:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'domain','http://123.456.789.1/wp');
```